# Django app not responding on Apache with wsgi_mod

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I'm trying to setup a Django website through Apache. For this I'm using a virtual machine running CentOS7 and use Apache 2.4.6.

I've created a virtual environment with Python (3.6.2), installed Django (1.10.05) and mod-wsgi (4.5.18). Started new Django project, migrated database, launched developer server on address 0.0.0.0:8003 and from outside the VM I can connect to `<VMs IP>:8003` without problem. However without the developer server, trying to relay on Apache, it does not work. My browser just says that it's unnable to connect to website and indeed, Apache's access log does not contain any trace of connection attempt. Same Apache hosts also another application written in Perl and it's working properly over its dedicated port.

Bit of my settings.py that might be informative for you

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]', '<VMs address>']
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

And my httpd.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8003>
# using port 8003, because 80 is used by another app. Both ports are open on firewall
    Alias /static /var/www/zdm_ebok/static
    <Directory /var/www/zdm_ebok/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/zdm_ebok/zdm_ebok>
      <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
       </Files>
    </Directory> 
    WSGIDaemonProcess zdm_ebok python-path=/var/www/zdm_ebok:/var/www/zdm_ebok/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup zdm_ebok
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/zdm_ebok/zdm_ebok/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

I've granted access (664) access and ownership to user that Apache is using, so that's probably not it.

Do you have any other ideas on what could I've done wrong?

**EDIT**

I switched ports with the other app, so that Django now works on port 80, I get 503 Service Unavailable error. I then managed to fix with with setting `WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi` in httpd.conf and adding `user=#1000` in WSGIDaemonProcess (1000 is id of my main user). However when I brought it back to port 8003 (so that my other app can work on 80) it's not responding again.

**SOLUTION**

Dunno if I should remove this or not, but maybe for somebody out there who is equally illiterate in Apache as I am, this will be useful. The single thing I forgot to do, was add "Listen 8003" in httpd.conf so that Apache would start listening for the new port.

Comment: were you able to find solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on one of my server and it is working properly. Try this,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName localhost.localdomain
  ServerAlias ipaddress

  DocumentRoot /var/www/projectname
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/projectname/projectname/wsgi.py

  Alias /static/ "/var/www/projectname/projectname/static/"
  <Directory "/var/www/projectname/projectname/static">
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/projectname
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. I tried this (replacing with my own paths of course) and several variations of it. Result is always the same: Apache starts properly, but does not react to requests.